# cypress not executing "then" portion

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to write a custom cypress command but the code in my then portion is not executing. any help will be appreciated thanks
my command looks similar to this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("ex", () => {
  const links=[]
  cy.get("*[class='link post']").each((link)=>{
    links.push(link.href)
  }).then(() => {
    var i=0;
    while (links[i]) {
      cy.visit(link)
      i++
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Please never put code as an image on here :) It becomes difficult for us to try it on our own.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but I am on a remote machine and I cant copy from it. sorry

Comment: .then(() could it be this? but it needs to be this? .then(), I'm not sure I've never really used this command before or this library, but that seems the most obvious here

Comment: and I gotta say, you really need to format your code properly, because it is very hard to follow all the curly braces and parenthesis at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Kerry's answer,

The parameter given to a `.then()` callback is a jQuery object, containing one or more elements found by `cy.get(...)`

To iterate over the elements, you need to de-structure the jQuery object with the spread operator,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("visitLinks", () => {
  cy.get("*[class='link post']")
    .then($links => {                          // $links is a jQuery wrapper

      [...$links].forEach(link => {            // link is a raw element
        const url = link.getAttribute('href')  // apply DOM method
        cy.visit(url)
      })

    })
});
```

or if you want to use the Cypress iterator `.each()` instead of `.then()`,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("visitLinks", () => {
  cy.get("*[class='link post']")
    .each($link => {                      // jQuery wrapped element

      const href = $link.attr('href')     // apply jQuery method
      cy.visit(href)         

    })
});
```

**However**

It's going to break.

`cy.visit()` navigates the page, which changes the DOM in the page, so on the 2nd iteration of `.each()`, Cypress sees things have changed and crashes (probably a "detached element" error).

You should separate the query (grabbing the links) from the action (visiting them).

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getLinks", () => {
  
  const found = [];

  cy.get("*[class='link post']")
    .each($link => {                      // jQuery wrapped element

      const href = $link.attr('href')     // apply jQuery method
      found.push(href)      

    })
    .then(() => found)                    // wait until iteration finishes
                                          // then return the array of links    
});
```

Use it like this

```js
cy.getLinks()
  .then(links => {
    links.forEach(link => cy.visit(link))
  })
```

Comment: This is an awesome addendum to my answer, and should be marked as the answer. Thanks for the detail and clarity!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things going on here we should step through.

In your `each()` block, `link.href` will return an undefined value, so when you get to your `then` method, you have no links in your array to visit. Instead of `links.push(link.href)`, try `links.push(links.attr('href')` to grab the value of your `href` attribute.

In your `then` method, your `while` loop isn't the most efficient way of looping through your array (and it will most likely error out for you with an undefined value). You should instead use a `.forEach()`, like so:

```
links.forEach((link)=>{
  cy.visit(link)
)
```

If you do not need to persist the `links` array, then your entire command can be majorly simplified:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("ex", () => {
  cy.get("*[class='link post']")
    .then((links) => {
      links.each((link)=>{
        cy.visit(link.attr('href'))
      })
    })
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work cypress returns links.forEach is not a function

Comment: @Alien0w0 Answer updated. Try `links.each` instead of `links.forEach`.

Comment: Either replace `.then(` with `.each(` or destructure the jQuey `links` object with `[...links].forEach(link => ...`.